# How to debug PyQt5 appcrash on exit

Tags: python, debugging, crash, pyqt, py2exe

I have been developing a PyQt5 software for a while now. I have managed to package my Python 3 PyQt5 software with py2exe fine in past with everything working perfectly.

However, now I have encountered an issue where the packaged exe-program will crash when user exits. More specifically I get APPCRASH with following details

> Problem signature:
>   Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
>   Application Name:   Sotilasmatrikkelit.exe
>   Application Version:    0.0.0.0
>   Application Timestamp:  54467a51
>   Fault Module Name:  PyQt5.QtCore.pyd
>   Fault Module Version:   0.0.0.0
>   Fault Module Timestamp: 549be77e
>   Exception Code: c0000005
>   Exception Offset:   0010c185
>   OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
>   Locale ID:  1035
>   Additional Information 1:   0a9e
>   Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>   Additional Information 3:   0a9e
>   Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

I never get this crash when running the software from Pycharm during the development. Any idea of how to debug this or what could be the cause in general?

I suspect this might have something to do with memory management (that PyQt doesn't delete all the resources properly on exit and therefore segfaults) but does anyone have any good suggestions to figure out the exact problem without better debug information? Should I try to do some kind of cleanup on exit? Atm I start the software like this:

```
def start():
  import sys
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  fixingtool = Mainwindow(app)
  fixingtool.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Additional investigation seems to suggest that I get Access Violation which is caused by C++ null-pointer. Sounds scary since I don't know too much of PyQt debugging. Anyway, I found an area on my businesslogic code which if removed will remove the problem. However, this code has nothing to do with PyQt and is just regular Python code and shouldn't differ in any way. Strangest part is that if I remove certain functions from the code, problem disappears even though functions are not called during runtime meaning that just importing the file with those functions cause the problem. Below is a code sample:

```
import re

from books.karelians.extraction.extractors.baseExtractor import BaseExtractor
from books.karelians.extraction.extractionExceptions import *
from books.karelians.extraction.extractors.dateExtractor import DateExtractor
from shared import textUtils
from books.karelians.extractionkeys import KEYS
from interface.valuewrapper import ValueWrapper
from shared import regexUtils
from books.karelians.extraction.extractors.professionextractor import ProfessionExtractor

class SpouseExtractor(BaseExtractor):


    def extract(self, text, entry):
        super(SpouseExtractor, self).extract(text)
        self.entry = entry
        self.PATTERN = r"Puol\.?(?P<spousedata>[A-ZÄ-Öa-zä-ö\s\.,\d-]*)(?=(Lapset|poika|tytär|asuinp))"
        self.NAMEPATTERN = r"(?P<name>^[\w\s\.-]*)"
        self.OPTIONS = (re.UNICODE | re.IGNORECASE)    #TODO: TRY IGNORE CASE?
        self.REQUIRES_MATCH_POSITION = False
        self.SUBSTRING_WIDTH = 100

        self.hasSpouse = False
        self.spouseName = ""
        self.profession = {KEYS["profession"] : ValueWrapper("")}

        self.initVars(text)
        self._findSpouse(text)
        return self._constructReturnDict()

    def initVars(self,text):
        pass

    def _findSpouse(self, text):
        try:
            self.foundSpouse = regexUtils.safeSearch(self.PATTERN, text, self.OPTIONS)
            self.hasSpouse = True
            self._findSpouseName(self.foundSpouse.group("spousedata"))
            self._setFinalMatchPosition()
        except regexUtils.RegexNoneMatchException:
            pass

    def _findSpouseName(self, text):
        try:
            name = regexUtils.safeSearch(self.NAMEPATTERN, text, self.OPTIONS)
            self.spouseName = name.group("name").strip()
            self._findProfession(text[name.end():])
        except regexUtils.RegexNoneMatchException:
            self.errorLogger.logError(SpouseNameException.eType, self.currentChild)

    def _findProfession(self, text):
        professionExt = ProfessionExtractor(self.entry, self.errorLogger, self.xmlDocument)
        professionExt.setDependencyMatchPositionToZero()
        self.profession = professionExt.extract(text, self.entry)


    def _setFinalMatchPosition(self):
        #Dirty fix for inaccuracy in positions which would screw the Location extraction
        self.matchFinalPosition = self.foundSpouse.end() + self.matchStartPosition - 4

    def _constructReturnDict(self):
        print(self.profession)
        return {KEYS["spouse"]: ValueWrapper({ KEYS["hasSpouse"]:  ValueWrapper(self.hasSpouse),KEYS["spouseName"]:  ValueWrapper(self.spouseName), KEYS["spouseProfession"]: ValueWrapper(self.profession[KEYS["profession"]].value) })}
```

Here if I remove or comment away all functions "initVars()" program exits properly. What gives?

Comment: I found a one strange place in my code where if I removed a function I never used (had forgotten to remove it) the problem went away. However, in application there is another area of completely normal looking code which when imported somehow messes up the garbage collection on exit. I get Access Violation.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a solution to a problem itself but I'm leaving this here in case someone encounters a similar issue.

Today I decided to try cx_freeze instead of py2exe figuring that maybe the problem is with py2exe since the whole issue is not happening when running the application with normal python interpreter.

Turns out I was right and problem seemed to magically disappear after I packaged the app using cx_freeze instead of py2exe. I didn't do any changes to code. Someone more knowledgeable than me about how py2exe and cx_freeze work might be able to explain the difference. My wild guess is that for some reason the exiting from the Python interpreter is not handled perfectly in py2exe case somehow messing the end garbage cleanup. I have no idea if this is py2exe's or my fault by not configuring py2exe properly.

In any case I'm happy it works now since yesterday was a really frustrating day.